# Remove dynamically generated <div> on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

I am trying to a `<div>` when it is clicked. When I tried with `.live()` it shows me:

> object has no method live()

I am using jQuery version 1.9, so `live` has been removed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addhelper').click(function(){
        $('div#containerr').append('<div class ="helpcont"><input type="text" name="helper_caption[]" class="input-large" placeholder="Caption">'+
      '<input type="text" name="helper_url" class="input-large" placeholder="Url">'+
      '<input type="text" name = "helper_source" class="input-large" placeholder="Source"><button class = "remove" type="button">remove</button></div>');
    });

    $("button.remove").on({
        click: function(){
            $(this).remove('div.helpcont');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this is my fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/K8cUC/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#containerr").on('click', '.remove', function(){
  $(this).closest('.helpcont').remove();
});
```

`#containerr` = the closest parent that is **not** added dynamically

`click`       = event (you can add multiple events by separating them with spaces)

`.remove`     = the selector on which to trigger the event

---

PS: Use selectors like `#id` instead of `element#id`. IDs should be unique anyway, so there's no need to do it the slow way, by making jQuery retrieve all DIV elements, and then searching for the one with the given ID.

Comment: `$("button.remove").on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent('.helpcont').remove();
});` even this also not woking

Comment: @pony can u explain me this line in brief ?`$("div#containerr").on('click', '.remove', function()`